# union of 2 sets; return simple object - C++

Tags: c++

What is the best way to implement the following?  I am trying to find the union of 2 sets.  I am creating 2 objects (one called set1 and one called set2).  I aim to create a 3rd object that is a UNION of the two without having to use a copy constructor.  Using dynmanic memory allocation and pointers and/or references is a must. Thanks to anyone to solves this dilemma and any pointers (no pun intended) would help.

Thanks coders.

THE HEADER file

```
                #ifndef INTEGERSET_H_
                #define INTEGERSET_H_

                class IntegerSet
                {
                private:
                    int * set;
                    int set_size;
                public:
                    IntegerSet(int size);    //default constructor
                    ~IntegerSet();           //destructor
                    IntegerSet * unionOfSets(const IntegerSet & set2);      
                    void insertElement(int k) const;
                    void printSet(int size) const;
                };
                #endif
```

THE MAIN file

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include "integerset.h"

            using std::cout;
            using std::endl;

            int main()
            {
                IntegerSet set1(11);

                //testing below
                set1.insertElement(3);
                set1.insertElement(4);
                set1.insertElement(6);
                set1.insertElement(10);

                set1.printSet(11);
                cout << endl;

                IntegerSet set2(8);
                set2.insertElement(3);
                set2.insertElement(6);
                set2.insertElement(7);

                set2.printSet(11);
                cout << endl;



                IntegerSet * obj3 = new IntegerSet(11);
                obj3 =  set1.unionOfSets(set2);                    
                obj3->printSet(11);

            //  system("pause");
                return 0;
            }
```

THE IMPLEMENTATION FILE

```
            #include "integerset.h"
            #include <iostream>

            IntegerSet::IntegerSet(int size)
            {
                set = new int[size];
                set_size = size;                    
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    set[i] = 0;
            }

            IntegerSet::~IntegerSet()
            {
                delete [] set;
            }

            void IntegerSet::insertElement(int k) const
            {
                (*this).set[k] = 1;
            }

            void IntegerSet::printSet(int size) const
            {
                int temp = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    if (set[i] == 1)
                    {
                        std::cout << i << " ";
                        temp++;
                    }
                }
                if (temp == 0)
                    std::cout << "----";
             }


            IntegerSet * IntegerSet::unionOfSets(const IntegerSet & set2) //make this return the union of 2 sets; THIS and the passed ARG reference; return address
            {


                   return this;
            }
```

Comment: Why must we use dynamic memory? Also try to trim down the code to what's relevant to your question. Also using `(*this)` is unnecessary

Comment: I trimmed it down a bit;  I left all the important code so it can be run by just copy/pasting.  Basically, the main is filling up 2 objects seperately and the object is dynamic (to force me not to make a copy constructor) The THIS usage is practice.

Comment: @Duknov007 Implement a copy constructor and return by value. Any other way of solving this is going to get very messy.

Comment: This one is getting hairy indeed.  Am I missing something but is best and/or only way to compare the 2 objects by looping inside them?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the standard libraries [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)? There are a number of set-operations in [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Comment: Teacher wants it this way.  The instructions are a bit crude and I know there are easiers implementations, but she makes it sound so simple.  Feel free to decipher these instructions:


1. Provide a unionOfSets member function that creates a third IntegerSet that is the union of two existing IntegerSet instances (so the third set created by this function contains all the members in the two sets used to create it – so if one or both of the sets the union is performed on has an element in it, the third set will have that element).

Comment: It should have an IntegerSet parameter (there is also a way that works with two IntegerSet parameters and returns nothing (is void) as well).  It should either return an IntegerSet that represents the union of the two IntegerSets it operated on (be careful how you do this, don’t return something that no longer exists.  You will most likely either have to use some pass by reference IntegerSet parameters or some parameters are pointers to IntegerSets.

Comment: Above are the instructions for that one Union function^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Random morning rant

What you try to create is more a `std::bitset` than a `std::set`. A set is usually [*"a collection of well defined distinct objects"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) (Cantor's definition is a little bit more complex, but lets stick to this). As such, a set could contain several pairwise unrelated objects.

Now, after this has been said, have a look at [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Note that its size is fixed by the template parameter `N`. `std::bitset::set` is almost equivalent to your `IntegerSet::insertElement`, except that it throws `std::out_of_range`. This I  recommend you to check your index for valid position:

```
void IntegerSet::insertElement(int k) const
{
    if( k < 0 || k >= set_size)
        throw std::out_of_range; 
    else
        this->set[k] = 1;
}
```

However, `std::bitset` doesn't support unions, so it's time to address your meain conern.

#### IntegerSet::unionofSets

Have a look at those lines.

```
IntegerSet * obj3 = new IntegerSet(11);
obj3 =  set1.unionOfSets(set2);
```

The first line initializes `obj3` with a pointer which contains the memory for a newly created IntegerSet with an internal set of size 11. And in the next line, your throw that pointer away. So you're throwing away resources and create a memory leak.

If you were to create a *new* IntegerSet your solution would be quite simple:

```
IntegerSet IntegerSet::unionOfSets(const IntegerSet & set2) const
{
    IntegerSet tmp (std::max(set2.set_size, this->set_size));

    for(int i = 0; i < set_size; ++i)
        tmp.set[i] = this->set[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < set2.set_size; ++i)
        tmp.set[i] |= set2.set[i];

    return tmp;
}
```

But your implementation changes the object it has been called from, so it isn't `const` and a little bit different:

```
IntegerSet * IntegerSet::unionOfSets(const IntegerSet & set2) // not const!
{
    if(set2.set_size > set_size){
        // the resulting set is bigger, we need new memory
        int * newset = new int[set2.set_size];

        // copy old values
        for(int i = 0; i < this->set_size; ++i)
            newset[i] = this->set[i];

        // replace old size
        this->set_size = set2.set_size;
        delete[] this->set; // remove old data
        this->set = newset; // replace pointer
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < set2.set_size; ++i)
        this->set[i] |= set2.set[i];

    return this;
}
```

This should be sufficient. Keep in mind that you must not use `new IntegerSet` in order to create a union:

```
IntegerSet * obj3 = new IntegerSet(11); // new memory, lets say obj3 = 0x500a
obj3 = set1.unionOfSets(set2); // new memory gone forever

if(obj3 == &set1)
    std::cout << "obj3 is a pointer to set1, changes to obj3 will affect set1" << std::endl;
```

If you don't want to create this behaviour use the first version with the temporary.

Also, please check whether [`std::set<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is sufficient for you, as you can use [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) from `<algorithm>`.

#### EDIT

> 1. Provide a unionOfSets member function that creates a third IntegerSet that is the union of two existing IntegerSet instances (so the third set created by this function contains all the members in the two sets used to create it – so if one or both of the sets the union is performed on has an element in it, the third set will have that element)

In this case forget about `IntegerSet * IntegerSet::unionOfSets(const IntegerSet&)` and use `IntegerSet IntegerSet::unionOfSets(const IntegerSet&) const` (the first variant with a returned object instead of a returned pointer).

#### EDIT2

As you didn't follow the rule of three, the memory in the returned `IntegerSet` will be invalid. You would either have to implement a copy constructor/assignment operator in order to fix this, or provide a new object with dynamic storage duration (`new`). For this you would just have to adjust the method a little bit:

```
IntegerSet * IntegerSet::unionOfSets(const IntegerSet & set2) const
{
    IntegerSet * tmp  = new IntegerSet( set2.set_size > this->set_size ? set2.set_size : this->set_size);

    for(int i = 0; i < set_size; ++i)
        tmp->set[i] = this->set[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < set2.set_size; ++i)
        tmp->set[i] |= set2.set[i];

    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: I am reading and dissecting this; looks slick and well thought out.  I will update.

Comment: Still trying to figure out your edit.  I prefer returning a pointer but let me see here..

Comment: @Duknov007: To be honest the *default* copy/move constructor `IntegerSet::IntegerSet(const &IntegerSet)` or `IntegerSet::IntegerSet(IntegerSet &&)` is going to be used in my example. It's defined by the compiler and will only copy the values. However, your instruction states the following: "creates a third `IntegerSet`". This indicates that your original `IntegerSet` shouldn't be modified. This means you have to create a *new* object. You could use dynamic allocation (`new`) for this, but it's not necessary. Just return a new `IntegerSet`.

Comment: A compile error on this line:
  IntegerSet tmp (std::max(set2.size,this->size));
IntegerSet can only take one argument and it is the int..

Comment: Did you include `<cmath>`? Otherwise just use `set2.size > this->size ? set2.size : this->size`.

Comment: Did you compile to see if it runs?

Comment: @Duknov007: I made a typo. The member which contains the size is called `set_size` and not `size`. And no, I didn't compile it before your last comment, however I just did and with the fixed typo it runs :).

Comment: Now, I am trying to use the implementation in main but since we returned an object and not a ref to one, this doesn't work:
           IntegerSet set3(11);

           set3 = set1.unionOfSets(set2);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17588/discussion-between-zeta-and-duknov007)

Comment: Is it possible to break this part down:
IntegerSet * tmp  = new IntegerSet(set2.set_size > this->set_size ? set2.set_size : this->set_size);

Comment: It it pretty elaborate and I achieved the same results with a simple integer int the argument.  I might be off though but please do explain the logic in the argument; it have barely used the ternary ? operator..

Answer (score 1):

Using standard facilities...

- `std::vector` is better than a hand-rolled array
- `std::sort` and `std::unique` are goodness

Therefore:

```
std::vector<int> set1;
set1.push_back(1); // ... and others

std::sort(set1.begin(), set1.end());   // sorts
std::unique(set1.begin(), set1.end()); // removes duplicates


// same with set2


std::vector<int> set3(set1);
set3.insert(set3.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end());

std::sort(set1.begin(), set1.end());   // sorts
std::unique(set1.begin(), set1.end()); // removes duplicates
```

Comment: +1 for the standard faclities; for learning purposes though I had to find out the other methods.

Comment: IntegerSet * tmp  = new IntegerSet(set2.set_size > this->set_size ? set2.set_size : this->set_size);

Comment: do you understand that segment? I questioned the writer of that above.